# Question about obj

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

I'm reading a book "A history of religion in 5 1/2 objects" these days, and one sentence is quite tricky for me.

> Our bodies are a matrix of connecting points that, when used appropriately, allow us to relate to and draw breath, meaning, and inspiration from the environment around (Plate, S. Brent. *A History of Religion in 5½ Objects* (p. 5). Beacon Press)

It seems like people are allowed to relate and draw breath. But, I don't get why the objects meaning, inspiration, and environment are placed behind of breath. These could have been written right after "relate to".

Comment: It is an oddly constructed sentence. Presumably the author is saying that we relate to the environment and draw (breath, meaning and inspiration) from it, but I don't understand what s/he means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to *relate* to and *draw* **ALL** of the following things: *breath*, *meaning*, and *inspiration*.

If two verbs can apply to a complement, combining them with *and* is normal.

> I washed and dried the clothes = I washed the clothes and I dried the clothes

It's possible to stick separate prepositions after one, some, or all verbs; in order to "position" the complement for one of the verb's in a way that makes sense.

> I paid for and threw out the junk = I paid for the junk and I threw out the junk

> I walked to and ate at the park = I walked to the park and I ate at the park

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is rather clumsy, but might perhaps be a bit more understandable if we added some dashes.

> Our bodies are a matrix of connecting points that, when used appropriately, allow us to relate to - and draw breath, meaning, and inspiration from - the environment around us.

So now we can understand it as two sets of verbs applying to the same object: the environment. Rephrasing again:

> ... connecting points that [...] allow us to relate to the environment around us and draw breath, meaning and inspiration from it.

(I still don't think there is any actual *meaning* there, but that might be par for the course in such a book.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!